# Granting multiple bounties

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I've recently asked a question where I was pleasantly surprised by the merit of answers. I did post a bounty that since has been granted automatically, with half of the amount (got a bit sidetracked and wasn't able to grant the bounty before the deadline)

I'd like to grant additional bounties to other answers, with similar amounts as the automatically awarded one, but the lowest option is 300 which is quite more than the current bounty on answer - 75 (I'm more about fairness of the rewards).

What can I do at this point?

Comment: the next bounty always needs to be higher then the previous one. There is no option to change this, except asking someone else to start the bounty.

Comment: The only exception is for 500 rep. That's the max bounty, and it's the only value you can give out several of on the same question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @RageFoxx it does explain how the bounty system work; it doesn't help me with how I want to approach this, but I guess that's the limitation of bounty system.

Comment: Unfortunately it is static in the regard of how you intend to use it, unless you evenly distribute 500 point bounties, as Zoe has mentioned there is no way to evenly distribute it below that.